# Equal coordinates and square aspect ratio with log scale in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, aspect-ratio

I am trying to generate a set of plots with log-scaled axes and the same coordinates on both axes, as well as a square aspect ratio. Let's consider the following hypothetical data:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(30, 50, 20)
y <- x + 20 + rnorm(30, 0, 10)
```

By using the code below, I obtain a rectangular plot:

```
p <- qplot(x, y) + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log2") + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log2") + 
  coord_equal()
```

[image: rectangular plot]

Now if I try to force the aspect ratio to 1:1 with the `theme()` function, it breaks the equal coordinate system:

```
p + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
```

[image: square plot]

Is there a way to get both the equal scaling and the square aspect ratio that does not imply to manually change the limits for each graph?
I would need to apply the same code to a whole series of data with different values and thus different limits.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `ggplot2` will scale based on your data.  But most of the `scale_xxx` functions provide a `limits` parameter that you can fine tune.  Using your above example

```
p <- qplot(x, y) + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log2", limits=c(8,128)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log2", limits=c(8,128)) + 
  coord_equal()
p + theme( aspect.ratio=1 )
```

[image]

You also didn't need to provide the `theme` if you used `coord_fixed()` instead of `coord_equal()`.

```
p <- qplot(x, y) + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log2", limits=c(8,128)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log2", limits=c(8,128)) + 
  coord_fixed( ratio=1 )
p
```

**EDIT #1**

Didn't see that one of you random x points was less than 8.  Revised code

```
p <- qplot(x, y) + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log2", limits=c(4,128)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log2", limits=c(4,128)) + 
  coord_fixed( ratio=1)
p
```

[image]

**EDIT #2** (Per additional rewording in the question)

If you want the range to be scaled dependent on your data, simply use the `range()` function in base R.  So using the above variables...

```
xy.limits <- range( c(x,y) )

p <- qplot(x, y) + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log2", limits=xy.limits) + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log2", limits=xy.limits) + 
  coord_fixed( ratio=1)
p
```

Now if you want to limits to be clean multiples of 2, then you will have to do some data manipulation based on the computed values of `xy.limits`, which is a numeric vector of length 2.

Comment: I reformulated my question since it was not clear. The data here is not my real data, and I am trying to apply this to a whole set of values with different limits, so manually setting the limits for each graph is not possible.